# Formula/Algorithm to get negation 8-bit hexadecimal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am looking for a mathematical formula / algorithm to find the negation of a 8-bit hexadecimal without having to expand into a binary form.

E.g;

0000BDDA -> 48602

FFFF4226 -> -48602

Need to get from 0000BDDA -> FFFF4226 without 2' complements / expanding it to binary.

I've been cracking my head at it but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with $32$-bit signed hexadecimal integers.

Half of the numbers ($00000000$ to $7FFFFFFF$) are the positive numbers; the other half ($FFFFFFFF$ to $80000000$) are the negative numbers.

Negative one is $FFFFFFFF$, and is calculated by

$$100000000 - 00000001 = FFFFFFFF.$$

Likewise, $-BDDA = -48602$ decimal is

$$100000000 - 0000BDDA = FFFF4226.$$